# Ecosystem naming discrepancies between LANDFIRE ESP and GAP/LANDFIRE National Terrestrial Ecosystems 2011 Datasets

Tags: ecology, classification, ecosystem

first post here! I am working on a project using the LANDFIRE ESP (environmental site potential) categories, and saw that on NatureServe Explorer I could find broader classifications for the categories provided in the ESP data like this example for the rocky mountain subalpine mesic-wet spruce fir forest and woodland:

[image: ivc heirarchy]

I found a table with all of these different levels of classification from the GAP/LANDFIRE National Terrestrial Ecosystems 2011 Dataset, but some of the ecosystem names from LANDFIRE ESP data do not match with any from the GAP dataset. for example, if you search for ecosystems with 'riparian' in the name you get pretty different results from both sets:
(GAP Dataset):

```
array(['northwestern great plains riparian',
       'western great plains riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'central appalachian riparian   forest modifier',
       'central interior and appalachian riparian systems',
       'ozark ouachita riparian',
       'south central interior small stream and riparian',
       'southeastern great plains riparian forest',
       'mississippi river floodplain and riparian forest',
       'mississippi river riparian forest',
       'southern piedmont small floodplain and riparian forest',
       'edwards plateau riparian',
       'columbia basin foothill riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'great basin foothill and lower montane riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'northern rocky mountain lower montane riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'rocky mountain lower montane riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'rocky mountain montane riparian systems',
       'rocky mountain subalpine montane riparian woodland',
       'north pacific lowland riparian forest and shrubland',
       'north pacific montane riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'california central valley riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'mediterranean california foothill and lower montane riparian woodland',
       'mediterranean california serpentine foothill and lower montane riparian woodland and seep',
       'north american warm desert lower montane riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'north american warm desert riparian systems',
       'north american warm desert riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'tamaulipan riparian systems',
       'rocky mountain subalpine montane riparian shrubland',
       'north american warm desert riparian mesquite bosque',
       'introduced riparian and wetland vegetation'], dtype=object)
```

(LANDFIRE dataset):

```
array(['inter mountain basins montane riparian systems',
       'north pacific lowland riparian forest and shrubland',
       'north pacific montane riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'rocky mountain montane riparian systems',
       'rocky mountain subalpine/upper montane riparian systems',
       'california montane riparian systems',
       'california central valley riparian woodland and shrubland',
       'north american warm desert riparian systems',
       'central interior and appalachian riparian systems',
       'gulf and atlantic coastal plain small stream riparian systems',
       'tamaulipan riparian systems', 'edwards plateau riparian'],
      dtype=object)
```

Any clues on this discrepancy or where I could find a lookup table that better matches the LANDFIRE ESP ecosystem categories? Thank you!!